# Will can Khan Academy Api totally be removed?

Tags: khan-academy

I read on the Khan Academy Github page https://github.com/Khan/khan-api  that the api will be deprecated by July 2020.

My questions are:

1. Will the whole Api be removed? Does that mean No api for personal projects?
2. Can I use Khan Academy API for personal projects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Comment: Web APIs often come and go, regardless of the company providing them. Software APIs like the Java standard library are more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Khan Academy API being removed thing, but to answer your second question:

Yes, you can use the API that Khan Academy is built on for personal projects. It is slightly different than pure Khan Academy code, but most of it is from the [ProcessingJS library](http://processingjs.org/reference/). See [this article](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/advanced-development-tools/a/using-processingjs-outside-khan-academy) for information on how to write Processing JS code for personal projects.

Comment: I have linked the Khan Academy's github page and it clearly mentions that they will remove all end points by July 1 2020. I was looking for an answer from a Khan Academy associate, to confirm that are those lines to be taken literally or are they planning something else for APIs.